# How can I rename columns and bind dataframes within a loop?

Tags: loops, binding, rename

Below is a sample of what I am trying to do:  I need to repeat columns 1&2 and extract columns 3:n and then combine the dataframes into 1 dataset.  How can I include the name function in the loop and also bind the dataframes? The column count can change on my real data therefore I need to make this dynamic...thank you.

```
library(dplyr)

nam <- c("j","g","r")
id <- c(1,2,3)
c1 <- c("fdg","afa","hdfg")
c2 <- c("gfdsfaf","sfgsgs","agafaf")
c3 <- c("hdfg","sgs","rtwe")

y <- data.frame(nam,id,c1,c2,c3)

cntr <- ncol(y)-2

#create dataframes
for(i in 1:cntr){
   (assign(paste0("r",i),as.data.frame(y[,c(1:2,i+2)])))
  }

#rename section
names(r1)[3] <- "c"
names(r2)[3] <- "c"
names(r3)[3] <- "c"

#stack dataframes
xyz <- bind_rows(r1,r2,r3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer posted by Stibu in 2016.  At least the renaming piece of the puzzle.

```
for (i in paste0("r",1:cntr)){
  call <- bquote(names(.(as.name(i)))[3] <- "c")
  eval(call)
}
```